# What nations don't start with Despotism?

Tags: freeciv

In Freeciv, the description of a nation usually says this:

"...history about nation... Initial government is Despotism."

Are there any nations that don't start with Despotism as their government?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nations that ship with Freeciv all have Despotism as their default government.

This is [referenced in the Nations article](http://freeciv.wikia.com/wiki/Nations):

> init_government: This is a single value attribute. A valid value would be one of the global defined governments. **This is always Despotism for default rulesets.**

You can confirm this by checking the files in nation/data, all of them either omit init_government or set it to Despotism.

However, this value can be overridden in a nation's ruleset file to be whatever that ruleset's creator would like.

Comment: e.g custom scenarios etc.